# Async Image Download and storing in an array of ImageView

Tags: android, asynchronous, png, imageview, android-asynctask

I have been searching for a while now for a way of doing an Async download of multiple images and storing them in an array. I have some GREAT example of this being used on Lists but I would like just to have a way of downloading these and use them later on.
Thanks for reading. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
         return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         //Do something with bitmap eg:
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
     }
 }

 private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url){
      try {
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
          return bitmap;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response but I seems to get an error: 
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
         return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
     }
It's complaining about the return statement: " return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);"

Comment: Because later in the code you set:  private void loadImageFromNetwork(String url)

Comment: sorry yes, i've edited the code to correct that, now the loadImageFromNetwork returns a bitmap! Opps!

Comment: I'm sorry I fooled around a little bit with the code and it's working. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks for this exceedingly simple solution!  A+++ would implement again

Answer (score 0):

you need to change 
new URL(imageURL) -> new URL(url)

and put return type, under the "e.printStackTrace();"
(return null;)

I checked it worked.